# A PowerShell script to set permissions to folder and its sub-folders

Tags: powershell

I have created a folder that has read/write permissions for the CREATOR, Domain Users and administrators. Its working well but when I try to access my share folder then I find that I have no write permission on that. I cannot create even a folder too.. pls help me.

```
$UserDir = "$HomeDir\$Sam"
$User = Get-QADUser -DisplayName "$Sam"
New-Item -Path $HomeDir -Name $Sam -ItemType Directory
Get-Acl "$UserDir"
$acl = Get-Acl $UserDir
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("SAHRDAYA\Domain Admins","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($userPrinc,@("FullControl", "Modify", "ReadAndExecute", "ListDirectory", "Read", "Write"), "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $UserDir $acl
```

Comment: Where is $userPrinc defined?

Comment: What are the actual permissions on that folder after running the script?

Comment: $userPrinc ia a variable which is defined in the top of the segment. Its value will be user1@sahrdaya.net